# How to get the duration of an HEVC video using Python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, duration, ffprobe, hevc

I have tried this code, but it can't retrieve the frame rate and frame count. Please help me.

```
import cv2

def with_opencv(filename):
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)

    frame_count = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    frame_rate = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

    return frame_count / frame_rate

print(with_opencv('vid.hevc'))
```

Comment: Is it printing anything? Is it opening the file? What output does it give you? have you tried either printing it inside the function or assigning a variable `results = with_opencv('vid.hevc')` to print it?

Comment: Prints -7686143364045.6455.
It has a problem with obtaining frame counts.

Comment: Which hevc file did you try? Are you sure it is a correct hevc stream?